# installing R 4.1.1 on my directory on public server, gcc compiler

Tags: r, gcc

I need to install the latest R version 4.1.1 on a public server in my own directory.
I have followed this procedure:

```
tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11
./configure --prefix=$HOME$Programme/zlib-1.2.11
make && make install

tar zxvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd bzip2-1.0.6
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
make clean
# modify the Makefile (original: CC=gcc after modification: CC=gcc -fPIC) as suggested [here][2]
make 
make install PREFIX=/opt/bzip2-1.0.6

tar zxvf xz-5.2.3.tar.gz
cd /root/xz-5.2.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3
make -j3
make install

tar zxvf pcre-8.40.tar.gz
cd /root/pcre-8.40
./configure  --prefix=$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40  --enable-utf8
make -j3 && make install

tar zxvf curl-7.52.1.tar.gz
cd /root/curl-7.52.1
./configure  --prefix=$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1
make && make install

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-3.3.1 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include -I/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/include"

The configure seemed to work:

R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    $HOME/Programme/R-3.3.1

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++  -std=c++0x -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:         

  Interfaces supported:      X11, tcltk
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS, cairo, ICU
  Options enabled:           shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      TIFF
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling
  Recommended packages:      yes

but when I call

make && make install

still "make" could not make it until the end:

...
  gcc -std=gnu99 -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L../../lib -L//HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L//HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L//HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L//HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L//HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib -o R.bin Rmain.o  -lR -lRblas
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.1, needed by ../../lib/libR.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblzma.so.5, needed by ../../lib/libR.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_fullinfo'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_lzma_preset@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_alone_decoder@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_crc64@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_raw_encoder@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_config'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_code@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_decoder@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_free'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_raw_decoder@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_exec'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_version_string@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_maketables'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_encoder@XZ_5.0'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_compile'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_study'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `pcre_version'
../../lib/libR.so: undefined reference to `lzma_end@XZ_5.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

...
make: *** [R] Error 1 

Follow up:
Based on thrig 's suggestion, I added the lines below to my .cshrc file

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib

and

source .cshrc 

problem solved!
Best Answer

This is the solution to the issue mentioned above

Follow the example to modify the configure file of R Then:

tar xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11
make && make install

tar zxvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd bzip2-1.0.6
make -f Makefile-libbz2_so
make clean

modify the Makefile (original: CC=gcc after modification: CC=gcc -fPIC) as suggested here

make 
make install PREFIX=$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6

tar zxvf xz-5.2.3.tar.gz
cd xz-5.2.3
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3
make -j3
make install

tar zxvf pcre-8.40.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.40
./configure  --prefix=$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40  --enable-utf8
make -j3 && make install

tar zxvf curl-7.52.1.tar.gz
cd curl-7.52.1
./configure  --prefix=$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1 --with-ssl
make && make install

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-3.3.1 --enable-R-shlib LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include -I/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/include"

Add the lines below to my .cshrc file

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.3/lib

and

source .cshrc 

Now go to R-3.3.1 directory:

make && make install 

it should work.
Related Question

    Install R in the own directory
    Ubuntu – How tonstall R’s devtools and digitize
```

...with some modifications, my final actual code is:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Programme/R-4.1.1 --enable-R-shlib --with-readline=no LDFLAGS="-L/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.4/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/lib -L/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/$HOME/Programme/zlib-1.2.11/include -I/$HOME/Programme/bzip2-1.0.6/include -I/$HOME/Programme/xz-5.2.4/include -I/$HOME/Programme/pcre-8.40/include -I/$HOME/Programme/curl-7.52.1/include" --with-x=no --with-pcre1
```

However, I cannot modify the .cshrc file as it is a public server I guess and I can't modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
I still get this error:

/usr/bin/ld: warning: libpcre.so.1, needed by ../../lib/libR.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblzma.so.5, needed by ../../lib/libR.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)

Any suggestion how to make the compiler recognizing those dependencies without editing the .cshrc file?

Comment: Do you have access to Docker on this machine? Do you really want to compile it or is just installing a binary fine? Old versions of gcc and the operating system will run into `LD_PATH` issues quite often.

Comment: I think I might have access, I think I need to compile it

Comment: There aren't any very special compiler flags used. Do you really care about a maximal optimized system or do you have very special hardware? For 99% of the use cases, one does not need to compile anything at all. Statistical workflows should be reproducible and have system level dependencies (curl and zlib in your case). Then we can just use docker as a package manager and create a fresh pre-compiled R container using `docker run -it --network host -v $HOME:/home/rstudio rocker/r-ver:4.1.1 R`

Comment: Do you really need exact versions of xz, and pcre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 99% of the use cases, one does not need to compile anything at all. Statistical workflows should be reproducible and have system level dependencies (curl and libz in your case). Then we can just use docker as a package manager and create a fresh pre-compiled R container:

Create a file called `Dockerfile` with the content

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.1
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y \
    zlib1g-dev curl libpcre3-dev liblzma-dev
```

Then go to the directory that contains the `Dockerfile` in your shell and run these commands:

```
docker build --tag my-r .
docker run -it --network host -v $HOME:/home/rstudio my-r
```

Comment: ok I will try as you suggested

Comment: hi, I do not think there is docker command install on the server

Comment: ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker says no file found

Comment: Try to get the infrastructure you need to do your work. Even for https://github.com/rstudio/r-builds you need root privileges